# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') at Array.map (<anonymous>) Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

This is my JSON File I am going to destructuring the array data here I facing one problem when I destructuring "points" object `<p>{current.points[0]}</p>` or `{points[0]}`I getting tittle named error. detail component

```
const FlipData = [
  {
    id: "1",
    tittle: "IT Manpower Consultant",
    points: [
      "Devops and IT consulting",
      "Renting Servers",
      "Cloud host and services",
      "Virtualizations ",
      "Security Solutions",
    ],
    detail:
      "We offer IT staffing solutions in multiple capabilities. We recruit for positions such as Devops Consulting, Systems Analyst, System Administrator, Technician, Help Desk Analyst, Security Specialist and more.",
    icon: icon,
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    tittle: "IT Managed Service's",
    points: [
      "Devops and IT consulting",
      "Renting Servers",
      "Cloud host and services",
      "Virtualizations ",
      "Security Solutions",
    ],
    detail:
      "We provide a systematic and professional approach to the management of IT service and enhances customer satisfaction through a more professional approach to service delivery.",
    icon: icon1,
  },
]
export default FlipData;
```

```
import React from "react";
import FlipData from "./FlipBoxData";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const FlipBox = () => {
  console.log(FlipData);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="flip-box">
        <div className="flip-box-heading">
          <h3>OUR iT SERVICES AND SOLUTIONS</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="container1">
          <div className="flip-box-main-grid">
            <div className="flip-box-grid">
              {/* start  */}
              {FlipData.map((current, id) => {
                const { tittle, detail, icon, points } = current;
                return (
                  <>
                    <div className="flip-box-grid-1" key={id}>
                      <div className="flip-main-card">
                        <div className="flip-front">
                          <img src={icon} alt="" />
                          <h4>{tittle}</h4>
                          <p>{detail}</p>
                          <Link to="\">Read More</Link>
                        </div>
                        <div className="flip-back">
                          <div className="flip-card-scroll">
                            <p key={id}>{points[0]}</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </>
                );
              })}
              {/* end */}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default FlipBox;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgamW.png)

how to destructuring the array object arrays `['points']`?

Comment: [Unable to replicate the problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-rain-9d6gtn?file=/src/FlipBox.js).  Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') at Array.map () Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

You cannot access element at *index* `0` when the array (`points`) is `undefined`. You could secure this case with e.g. *optional chaining* (`?`).

```
<p key={id}>{points?.[0]}</p>
```

More details about *optional chaining*: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining